# Import error for action for the rest_framework.decorators

Tags: python, docker, django-rest-framework

I'm running a docker container where I've installed, via pip, django rest framework v3.8.2. I updated my code to `from rest_framework.decorators import action`. Doing this causes an the import error. I've tried `docker-compose restart`, `docker-compose down`, `docker-compose up -d`. None of those seem to be picking up the correct DRF. I've run `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` and `pip freeze` and it spits out `djangorestframework==3.8.2`

What could I be missing? Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the dependency version, ***you have to build the image once again***. So. run these commands accordingly

```
docker-compose build

docker-compose up
```